# How to create multiple column families using some script?

Tags: shell, cassandra

I have to create Multiple Column Families in my keyspace. One way is to create the column families one by one.. But in my case, I have around 100 column families so I cannot do it one by one... So is there any way, I can create multiple column families through some sort of script which can create multiple column families for me in one short?

```
create column family USER_DATA_SECOND_1
with comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(DateType,UTF8Type)'
and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'
and gc_grace = 86400

create column family USER_DATA_SECOND_2
with comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(DateType,UTF8Type)'
and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'
and gc_grace = 86400

create column family USER_DATA_SECOND_3
with comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(DateType,UTF8Type)'
and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'
and gc_grace = 86400

....
....
....

create column family USER_DATA_SECOND_100
with comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(DateType,UTF8Type)'
and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'
and gc_grace = 86400
```

And also after creating these multiple column families.. Suppose if I need to drop all these column families again then how to do that using some script again?

Below is the way, I am creating the column families now from my local machine to my staging cassandra server one by one, which is not what I want..

```
C:\Apache Cassandra\apache-cassandra-1.2.3\bin>cassandra-cli -h sc-cdbhost01.vip.slc.qa.host.com
Starting Cassandra Client
Connected to: "Staging Cluster cass01" on sc-cdbhost01.vip.slc.qa.host.com/9160
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version 1.2.3

Type 'help;' or '?' for help.
Type 'quit;' or 'exit;' to quit.

[default@unknown] use profileks;
Authenticated to keyspace: profileks
[default@profileks] create column family USER_DATA_SECOND_1
...     with comparator = 'UTF8Type'
...     and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(DateType,UTF8Type)'
...     and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'
...     and gc_grace = 86400;
27fe1848-c7de-3994-9289-486a9bbbf344
[default@profileks]
```

Can anyone help me whether this is possible to create multiple column families through some sort of script and then drop those column families as well through some sort of script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the sample scripts

**Keyspace creation script**

```
drop keyspace my_keyspace;
create keyspace my_keyspace with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' and strategy_options = {replication_factor:1};
```

To execute it:

```
cassandra-cli -h <hostname> -p <port> -u <user> -pw <password> -f <keyspace_script>
```

---

---

**Schema creation script**

```
create column family USER_DATA_SECOND_1 with comparator = 'UTF8Type' and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(DateType,UTF8Type)' and default_validation_class = 'BytesType' and gc_grace = 86400;
create column family USER_DATA_SECOND_2 with comparator = 'UTF8Type' and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(DateType,UTF8Type)' and default_validation_class = 'BytesType' and gc_grace = 86400;
...
```

To execute it:

```
cassandra-cli -h <hostname> -p <port> -u <user> -pw <password> -k my_keyspace -f <schema_script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@TechGeeky

cassandra-cli -f  -k  will execute all the commands in your script file in the declared keyspace

For dropping and creating CF from scratch, we used to have a 2 script that does:

**Keyspace script**

1 drop keyspace xxx

2 create keyspace xxx with ...

**Structure script**

1 create column family ...

...

n. create column family

One important thing, the create column family should stay on 1 line. Remove all line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion... Can you provide a simple example  using script? I am not that much familiar with scripting language... It will help me to understand better with a simple example..Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SOURCE 'file'` command to execute the whole set of statements written in a file. Please Refer [link](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/source_r.html)

**e.g**: In a .txt file you have written some schemas, creation of keyspace, creation of column familie & lots of other relevant stuffs. Then use the SOURCE command to execute the all the statements inside the file.